# Conversion of Object to List of Object in a Request POJO Class(JAVA)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I have request class implemented with more than 20 variables like below

```
Class A {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    ....
}
```

Now I want to make address field as List address in the request How can I achieve this without affecting any other objects/methods/classes which are almost tightly coupled to this.

I tried to replicate same thing in different new class by adding List of String for address. Which includes lot of changes too, I am afraid code is already in production and I don't want other things get affected.

Comment: But how are you going to process this address - let say that you will keep somehow list of addresses in one string ("address1,address2,address3") then what should e.g. printAddress() method do? Technically what you are trying to do is quite easy (just create some kind of facade that will keep this string/list sorted out) but business logic anyway will change a lot!

Comment: I would capture the address list and store into DB. I know technically its too easy but  wanted it to happen without much change in business logic. I was hoping to have kind of bridge design pattern where in two classes compliment each other